# iText and counter-increment/counter-reset

Tags: html, css, pdf, itext, html-to-pdf

I'm currently using iText to take HTML and convert it to a PDF document. I'm attempting to use some CSS to create nested ordered list i.e.:

```
1
   1.1
   1.2
2
   2.1
   2.2
```

I've tested my CSS and it appears to work, however when I feed it into Itext it seems to ignore `counter-increment` and `counter-reset`.

The CSS that I'm using is:

```css
   ol {
     counter-reset: index
   }
   li {
     display: block
   }
   li:before {
     content: counters(index, ".") ") "; 
     counter-increment: index;
   }
```

Am I missing something, or does iText simply not recognize these selectors?

Comment: iText's XML Worker doesn't support the full CSS set of selectors. You are using selectors that aren't supported.

Comment: I tried your code http://jsfiddle.net/v80xdupk/. It works fine, well I am not aware about itext but as far as code is concerned, then it is correct.

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie Thanks for the confirmation, I had suspected as much

Answer (score 1):

Starting from version 7.0.3 iText, the `counter`, `counter-increment`, and `counter-reset` attributes are supported.